# Public static text box error

Tags: c#, windows

I declare a text box  form 1 "public static".After some time later open my c# window application project that text box is hidden automatically.how to prevent a text box in my form 1.
below deceleration.

```
       public static System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox textBox1;

         //  
        // textBox1
        // 
        Form1.textBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        Form1.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
        Form1.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        Form1.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(472, 256);
        Form1.textBox1.TabIndex = 5;
        Form1.textBox1.Text = "";
```

Comment: Because you are changing auto generate class. You need to add this code into method in the part of Form1, not in Form1.Designer

Comment: Don't mark a Control static, if you want to access a Control, make the Form static.

Comment: @JameyD: don't do that either. Provide methods on the form object to allow you to modify things in a controlled fashion.

Comment: Why do you need it to be public static? Let's restructure your program so you don't have to do that.

Comment: Am creating notepad application so i do a find function in form 2 that's y i am using public static

Comment: @kingKabil: don't do it that way. Share the data through shared objects, public instance properties or methods. Globals (which is what public static is) won't work. Also, you can never create more than one instance of Form2 this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public static System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox textBox1
  public static text box is a object its not show Form ,Remove the static     keyword in previous line

public System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox textBox1